# Why wordpress put jquery in front?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My friend wants to speed up his site.
He sent me some analysis

And this is the analysis

```
Your page has 1 blocking script resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
Remove render-blocking JavaScript:

    http://***.id/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
```

The problem with it is it's wordpress file.

Why the heck wordpress include jquery.js on top of website.

Shouldn't it be on the bottom?

Comment: Like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51140

Comment: It can be on either, though if it's at the bottom, make sure other scripts that use jQuery uses `$(document).ready(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use wp_deregister_script('jquery');
This function will be disable jquery and after this you can register jquery in footer using wp_footer action, but it's not good idea(some wp functions can be broken after this), you can try to deregister jquery, minify this and register it using wp_head action.
Or try to include it via async, just add "async" attribute to jquery script